# Click on boutton with javascript

Tags: javascript, console

I need you help plz !!

I try too click on boutton with the chrome console the code is like this :
[image: Code]

I already try code like :
$0.click()
But d'ont work

I hope someone can to help me

Thx

Answer (score 2):

[image: img1]Why don't you just try using

```js
document.querySelector("urbuttonuwannaclick").click();
```

or, find the element in the elements panel, and click it, then type

```js
$0.click();
```